# Android Socket.getchannel() method always returns null in javamail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, nio

IdleManager of javamail is not working in Android.

When I try to watch a folder with idlemanager, javamail throwing error message **Folder is not using SocketChannels** .  Android SocketChannel always returns null within the Socket.

After digging deep I came to know that when create a Socket from SSLSocketFactory, it's making SocketChannel null.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Here is the stacktrace

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Folder is not using SocketChannels
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager.watch(IdleManager.java:203)
 at com.sample,mail.ImapIdle$1.doInBackground(ImapPushNotification.java:120)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing this as a question. Why is there no stack trace, for example? And what does 'Android always returns null within the `Socket`' mean?

Comment: @EJP thanks for the quick response. Stacktrace added to the question

Comment: THat's one out of two issues, and now there is a third. What on earth does 'when create a `Socket` from `SSLSocketFactory`, it's making `SocketChannel` null' mean?

Comment: @EJP Please stop asking dumb questions.

Comment: Looks like [Bug 8399 - IdleManager fails on Android](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8399) will be fixed in the next release of JavaMail.

Answer (score 2):

Try [JavaMail 1.5.6](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) (just released).  It has some Android fixes.

I've dug into this a bit more and as far as I can tell this is a bug in Android that JavaMail can't easily work around.  **Please report this to Google.**  The following works on real Java but prints null on Android:

```
    Socket s = SocketChannel.open().socket();
    s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    Socket ss = ((SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).
                        createSocket(s, host, port, true);
    System.out.println("SocketChannel wrapped " + ss.getChannel());
```

Comment: I am using  Javamail 1.5.6

Comment: Did you set the `mail.imap.usesocketchannels` property?

Comment: Yes , I set `mail.imap.usesocketchannels` to true.   The same code is working in java but not working for Android

Comment: Sounds like another case where Android is not compatible with Java.  What's the stack trace from the exception?  Do you have a simple example that reproduces the problem?  What version of Android?

Comment: stacktrace has been included in my question and using the sample code from https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html. Am using Android 5.1

Comment: Does it work with JavaMail 1.5.5?  Is this a new bug?  You're definitely using android-mail.jar, right?

Comment: didn't work with javamail 1.5.5 and I am using android-mail.jar

Comment: I have posted the detail information in javamail forum

Comment: Yes this is what I was facing. Even I had gone through this code block in socketfetcher. I found a workaround for this. Will let you know if it works. Really thanks for wonderful support

Comment: I may have a workaround using reflection.  Contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com if you want to try it.

Comment: I never heard from you, but I pushed out a JavaMail 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT release that contains the workaround.